# Preview section is opening but an empty square in developer section of local. Any solution for this?

Tags: web, development-environment

To check the api preview, preview bar is opening but giving an empty square. How to solve this?

Just clicking on the preview tab in the developer mode(ctrl + shift + i) of local should give different tabs open including Headers, Payload, Preview, etc. I get everything else opened but not preview(it opens but an empty square)